# How to re-use common css rules in css( sass )

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I have a CSS stylesheet as below

```
.icon1 {
    &:after {
        content:"";
        float: right;
        width: 8px;
        height: 8px;
        border-radius: 100%;                  
        background-color: #4ac102;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }
}

.icon2 {
    &:after {
        content:"";
        float: right;
        width: 8px;
        height: 8px;
        border-radius: 100%;                
        background-color: #f1342f;
        display: block;       
        position: relative;
    }
}

.icon3 {
    &:after {
        content:"";
        float: right;
        width: 8px;
        height: 8px;
        border-radius: 100%;                
        background-color: #616a83;
        display: block;       
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

As you can see except for the background-color all the other properties are the same. Can I refactor this code in order to make it DRY?

Comment: This is kind of off-topic for SO. CodeReview *might* be a better fit...but check their guidlines first.

Comment: @Paulie_D why would you think its off topic ??

Comment: Because the code works....Tidying it or DRYing it up isn't really a SO problem.

Comment: So no process improvement questions should be asked on SO ? that's kinda harsh .

Comment: I didn't down vote...I'm saying that there is a dedicated Exchange site that's more appropriate.

Comment: I really dont worry about the downvotes - its not the end of life for me.. I am more worried about the comments .. the comments help me improve my questions.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Extend/Inheritance](http://sass-lang.com/guide) for this:

```
  .icons {
    content:"";
    float: right;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 100%;      
    display: block;       
    position: relative;
  }

  .icon1 {
    &:after {
      @extend .icons;             
      background-color: #4ac102;
    }
  }
  .icon2 {
    &:after {
      @extend .icons;             
      background-color: #f1342f;
    }
  }

  .icon3 {
    &:after {
      @extend .icons;             
      background-color: #616a83;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

For a CSS/SCSS solution with no additional classes:

```
.icon1, .icon2, .icon3 {
    &:after {
        /* shared code */
    }
}

.icon1 {
    &:after {
      /* unique code */
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution works, but if you are using sass, you'd mostly prefer to use inheritance.

Comment: agreed. I posted that for general usage, and because the OP code used nothing sass-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't better create one class in html which will be icons and one more class just for background color?
In this case you will have something like this:

```
<div class="icon icon-1"></div>
<div class="icon icon-2"></div>
<div class="icon icon-3"></div>
```

and styles like:

```
 .icon {
    content:"";
    float: right;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 100%;      
    display: block;       
    position: relative;
  }


.icon-1{
    background-color: #f1342f;
}
.icon-2{
    background-color: #616a83;
}
.icon-3{
    background-color: #4ac102;
}
```